# Проблема со временем в Docker-compose (Redis, Celery, Django)

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, redis, celery

Пишу сервис рассылки, на Django (Redis + Celery)

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "TZ=Europe/Moscow"
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  webapp:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: ["python3", "-u", "./src/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]


  worker:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./backend
    command: ['celery', '--workdir=./src', '-A', 'config', 'worker']
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./src ./src

CMD ["python3", "-u", "./src/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

В Django при поставке задачи использую функцию `apply_async(eta=datetime(2023, 10, 27, 10, 4))`

Проблема заключается в том, что нужно ставить на минус 3 часа, чтобы код обработался в нужное время. В докере, заметил что в сервисе redis в логах -3 часа. Добавил строку в docker-compose `environment: - "TZ=Europe/Moscow"`. В логах время изменилось, но на деле, всё так же надо выставлять на -3 часа. Не могу разобраться в чём проблема.

PS. В Django settings указаны время для приложения и для celery.

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

Comment: Добавили TZ для обоих контейнеров?

Comment: Для всех 3х добавилял. Проблема не решилась